# PostgreSQL boolean cast (0 as false)

Tags: postgresql, casting

I prefer 1/0 instead of t/f, so what should I use when converting boolean to integer?

```
select coalesce((null::boolean)::int, 0)
```

OR

```
select case null::boolean when 't' then 1 else 0 end
```

... something else?

Comment: What was wrong with you first expression? `select coalesce((null::boolean)::int, 0)`?

Comment: Was looking for idiomatic/succinct way to make conversion.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Regardless of which you do, a Boolean null does not equal false, any more than a numeric null equals zero.

Try:

```
Cast(col1 as integer)
```

If you really wanted to treat null as false then:

```
case when col1 then 1 else 0 end
```

It would be a Bad Thing though

Comment: Yes, of course; it's only that my model logic considers eventual nulls as false. Btw, is there a difference between cast function and col1::int?

Comment: "The CAST syntax conforms to SQL; the syntax with :: is historical PostgreSQL usage" http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-expressions.html

Comment: @mpapec that would be a matter for regret, and for considering how you got into such a state. Now it could be that nulls are entirely appropriate, which is a different matter of course. By my point was just that Null <> false